# How to print textfield's value in Django and Python?

Tags: python, django, textbox

I'm trying to create a very simple web page with **2 textfields**, **1 button** and **3 labels** to make it look like so:

```
First Name: [..........]   <-- label + textfield

Last Name: [...........]   <-- label + textfield

(Submit) <-- button

{Your full name is %FirstName% + %LastName% } <-- label
```

As you can see it's an extremely simple task. I could have easily done this in ASP.NET in 5 minutes but I am not very familiar with Django or Python, as I am just starting to learn the framework.

Thanks.

Comment: i guess you don't have enough django basic understood, you better read the doc http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/. Using form in Django must be easier, believe me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zomboid's comment is correct. It looks like you need to learn more about Django. You might want to take a look at [this chapter](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/) from The Django Book. That text is a bit outdated, but the fundamentals are the same.

Some general guidance: you need to point a URL (e.g., `/namegrabber`) to a view function. Inside that view function, you decide whether the user's doing a GET or a POST. If it's a GET, then instantiate an unbound form -- i.e., a form with no data -- and pass it to a template to be rendered. If it's a POST, then instantiate your form, populating it with `request.POST`. Then, take the data in your form's `cleaned_data` attribute and pass *that* to a template to be rendered.

Two other comments. First, as I mentioned, the text in The Django Book is a bit outdated. In particular, you'll need to somehow deal with Django's CSRF protection since your view will be handling POST requests, assuming you're using Django 1.2+. A nice overview of how to do that is [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/). Second, when you're building your form, you'll probably want to use `forms.CharField` for the data you're talking about.

Good luck! This *is* a five-minute task in Django once you're accustomed to the framework.

Answer (score 1):

On the python end of it, you can view these values by looking at request.POST["field_name"]. You can then pass these values to the template (different methods depending on which function you are using to call the template). Then the template will look something like

```
Your full name is {{ first_name }} {{ last_name }}
```

Let me know if you need more detail / examples.